# Firestore Nested Query in Flutter for List Building

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I have two collections in my firestore db; "queries" and "users". My requirement is to get all the queries with respect to specific flag from "queries" collection. Once done I need to check uid in each query and query my user's data using that uid from "users" collection. In this case I am fetching user's name and number using StreamBuilder in flutter. Below is my approach:

```
return new StreamBuilder(
  stream: db.collection("queries").where("isAttended", isEqualTo: false).snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
    if(!snapshot.hasData) return new Text("Loading...");
    return new ListView(
      children: snapshot.data.documents.map((document){
        String name = '';
        String number = '';
        var doc = db.collection("users").document(document["uid"]).get();
        doc.then((onValue) {
          number  = onValue.data['number'];
          name = onValue.data['name'];
        });
       return new ListTile(
         title: new Text(name),
         subtitle: new Text(number),
       ); 
      }).toList(),
    );
  },

);
```

Problem is onValue returns null. Please advise on my approach for querying data in the manner I specified above. TIA.

Comment: The `then()` callback only runs once the data is loaded, while the `return new ListTile()` that uses the data from the database runs straight away. I'm not enough of a Flutter expert to show you how to do this, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54651388) shows something similar (though not the same).

Answer (score 1):

Lets start,

This is your children list `List<Widget> children = [];`

Change your `ListView` children to `ListView(children: children, ...)`

And update your streambuilder like that,

```
if(!snapshot.hasData) return new Text("Loading...");
initChildren(snapshot); // here is important
return new ListView(...
```

And `initChildren` is

```
initChildren(snapshot) async {
  final list = await Future.wait(snapshot.data.documents.map((document) async {
    String name = '';
    String number = '';
    var doc = await db.collection("users").document(document["uid"]).get();
    doc.then((onValue) {
      number = onValue.data['number'];
      name = onValue.data['name'];
    });
    return new ListTile(
      title: new Text(name),
      subtitle: new Text(number),
    );
  }));
  setState(() => children = list);
}
```